# Is there a terraform interpreter?

Tags: terraform

I would like to see all attributes of my object in terraform for error checking.

So easiest way for me start a plan and go into an intepreter, where i could see the attributes of my object. Is there something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a *parser*, not an interpreter. Looking for that should bring up some options.
By the way, `terraform show` let's you transform a file with the output of `terraform plan` to JSON https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/json-format. That should be easy to parse.